# php read file every 2 seconds not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a file which will update every 2 seconds, i want read the log file and post it on a php file, but it's just reading the content of a file only 1 time and not getting updated every 2 seconds.
In this case not_insync_text value keep updating every 2 seconds.
Here is my code

```
<script>
    //var insync_text = <?php echo $_SESSION['IN_SYNC_COUNT'];?>;
   var not_insync_text = ["10", "11", "12", "13"];
     var question_text = ["20", "21", "22", "23"];
     var counter = 0;
     var insync = document.getElementById("insync");
     var not_insync = document.getElementById("not_insync");
     var question = document.getElementById("question");


function change() {
    <?php $output="";$output=exec('cat hello1.txt');?>
    <?php $insync_output="";$insync_output=exec('cat $INSYNC_METRICS_LOG_FILE');?>
    insync.innerHTML = "<?php echo $insync_output; ?>";
    not_insync.innerHTML = "<font color=red>" +not_insync_text[counter]+ "</font>";
    question.innerHTML = "<?php echo $output; ?>";
    counter++;
    if (counter >= not_insync_text.length) counter = 0;
}

change();
setInterval(function() {
    change()
}, 4000);
```

Here the hello1.txt and $INSYNC_METRICS_LOG_FILE will update with an incremental numbers    (1,2,3), i am facing same issue with $_SESSION['INSYNC_METRICS_VALUE'], it's only printing    one time untill unless i refresh the page, but i don't want to refresh so i am calling it    from setInterval.

Comment: stop mixing php and javascript ...will help sort out some confusion. They run in completely different environments

Comment: The `<font>` tag is depreciated in HTML 4 and not supported in HTML 5. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server which means all the PHP code is executed once when the page loads. All the PHP in your function change() spits out the values one time and not every time you call the function.

If you want to update without refreshing the page, you need to use AJAX.